# iReport 3.7 - Unable to create the report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-pdf

I am using the report wizard and was successfully created the new report, but when I clicked 'Finish" to generate the report, I am getting "unable to create the report". I selected "PDF Preview" on this report.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to help you. Have you looked in the iReport output or Report Problems windows? What kind of output do they contain?

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific about what you are trying to do. This looks more like an issue with a particular piece of software than something programming related to me.

Comment: There's no message on the Report Problem Windows. I got the Congratulations! You have successfully created a new report. Click Finish to generate it. Once I click finish message"unable to create the report'.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and found that I didn't have write permissions to the folder that IReport was using to create the report. If you modify permissions so that you have full control over that folder, it should fix the problem. (Or perhaps create it in some other place)

Answer (score 1):

I came across similar kind of situation .... what i did was rewrite the query through iReport query designer. even ";" character take as a invalid one with iReport though it is end character of other query editors. So better to go with iReport query designer and its easy.
Lal Ajith Kumara